# Transfer doctrine query to native SQL without function

Tags: php, doctrine

i'd like to ask if anybody can translate this PHP code (doctrine) to native SQL. I find out solution on one of my problem but only in doctrine and id like to see native SQL.

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.order >= :order')
        ->setParameter('order', $nextItem ? $nextItem->getOrder() : 0)
        ->andWhere('r.order < :order2')
        ->setParameter('order2', $item->getOrder())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Thank u very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `->getQuery()` you can call `->getSQL()`

In the Query class:

```
    /**
     * Gets the SQL query/queries that correspond to this DQL query.
     *
     * @return mixed The built sql query or an array of all sql queries.
     *
     * @override
     */
    public function getSQL()
    {
        return $this->parse()->getSqlExecutor()->getSqlStatements();
    }
```

### update

For whatever rewason, his code isnt in the project, and he isn't even using doctrine. I guess what he is looking for is this:

`SELECT * FROM  yourtable r WHERE r.order >= :order AND r.order < :order2`

Comment: I understand but i dont have doctrine in project so i cant execute it ...

Comment: so where is this code coming from?